# Where do you find quiet places to code?

Tags: environment

I'm currently working at home, but it's not always an ideal environment for coding. Where do you go when you need a quiet place to work for several hours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

earplugs or noise cancelling headphones

Comment: That, plus Pandora, Last.fm, or an iPod (or other MP3 player of choice) if you like music. Nothing beats that.

Comment: I wish I was one of those people who can concentrate with music playing. I can't think clearly with the distracting noise...

Answer (score 1):

I used to work from home, and it was fine until my youngest learned to walk then it was all over. Since then my company found some free space that is reserved for startups. if you are a new company there's a lot of great resources out there to tap into especially if you're near a decent university.

Otherwise, I've found that any place with wifi, and an outlet will work. Just be sure to bring your ipod, and if you have a pair of noise cancelling headphones then you can tune out just about anything.

Comment: I once tried to code with my kids around--because I didn't want to be isolated from the family.  Worst idea ever.  There were too many interruptions! It took me 3 entire days to iron out all the bugs I wrote that one evening! Ever since then, I lock myself in the office or bedroom...

Answer (score 1):

Try and find coworking facilities in your area. They generally provide adhoc on demand office space to people such as your self. Here in Seattle there is a place called Startpad that offers this service just to programmers. Otherwise a university library might be a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

An unpopular coffee shop.

(I suppose I could try a co-working facility, but they always seem so sterile and officelike.)

Answer (score 0):

Take pen and paper and travel to the woods. Well, at least this works if you don't need to code right away or have a laptop.

Comment: I can't write code on paper. Pseudo code kind of works out alright.

Comment: Works alright if you have a powerconverter or some spare batteries unless its Winter, and you live in a cold climate...be fun can you type that function before your fingers go numb....

Answer (score 0):

My home is pretty quiet so that usually works for me. Libraries have hot spots though. Maybe check yours out?

Answer (score 0):

My room. This way I can have my music, silence or whatever else I take interest to at the time.

Answer (score 0):

My den. With my desk, my chair, my computers, my keyboard, and my monitors setup exactly how I like them. When needed, there is also my door and my music.